# Como realizar búsqueda en filas secundarias (Datatables)

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Estoy en la creación de un datatable que usa filas secundarias y búsqueda de columnas (filtrado), pero en este caso me gustaría que al buscar los datos de mi datatable incluya los resultados de la fila secundaria.

Actualmente cuando se realiza la búsqueda, este va y busca sobre las filas primarias y no me muestra los resultados de las filas secundarias.

Comparto a continuación algo del código que tengo realizado hasta el momento.

La siguiente es la función en Javascript con la cual armo las filas secundarias.

```
/* Formatting function for row details - modify as you need */
function format(d) {
    // `d` is the original data object for the row
      let tabla = `<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: separate; border-spacing: 40px 5px;">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>
                                Fecha
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                Factura
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                Total
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                Estado
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>`;
                                                        
                            d.Factura.forEach(f => {                            
                                tabla += `<tr>                                                         
                                <td>${f.FechaFactura}</td>
                                <td>${f.Factura}</td>
                                <td>${f.Total}</td>     
                                <td>${f.Estado}</td>                                                                                            
                                <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ModalCargaFactura"`;
                                
                                  tabla += `>Cargar Documentos</button></td>                               
                                <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="MostrarDetalleFactura('${f.Factura}')">Ver Detalle</button></td>
                                </tr>`;
                            });
                       tabla += '</tbody></table>';
                       return tabla;    
}
```

El siguiente es el código con el cual construyo las filas primarias.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

   $('#example').dataTable( {
        responsive : true,
         ajax : {
             "type": 'POST',
             "url" : './utileria.php',  
             "dataType": 'JSON',             
             "cache": false,
            "data": mdata,
         },
         language : {
            "lengthMenu": "Mostrar _MENU_ registros",
            "zeroRecords": "No se encontró nada",
            "info": "Mostrando del _START_ al _END_ de un total de _TOTAL_",
            "infoEmpty": "No hay registros",
            "emptyTable": "No hay datos para mostrar",
            "loadingRecords": "Cargando...",
            "processing": "Procesando...",
            "search": "Buscar:",
            "infoFiltered": "(filtrado de un total de _MAX_ registros)",
            "paginate": {
                "first": "Primera",
                "last": "Última",
                "next": "Siguiente",
                "previous": "Anterior"
            }
         },    
         columns: [          
             {
                 "className":      'details-control',
                 "orderable":      false,
                 "data":           null,
                 "defaultContent": ''
             },
             { "data" : "Orden" },
             { "data" : "Fecha" },            
             { "data" : "Tipo" },                  
        ],
         order : [[1, 'desc']],
    } );

    
    // Add event listener for opening and closing details
    $('#example').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
      var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        var row = $('#example').DataTable().row(tr);
        if (row.child.isShown()) {
            // This row is already open - close it
            row.child.hide();
            tr.removeClass('shown');
        }
        else {
            // Open this row
            row.child(format(row.data())).show();
            tr.addClass('shown');
        }
    });

});
```

Espero que alguien me pueda dar un poco de orientación en como realizar búsqueda y que este incluya los resultados de las filas secundarias.

Comment: Puedes aclarar mejor tu pregunta?

Comment: @AmilcarAngeles Te aclaro mejor la pregunta en este comentario, sucede que cuando se realiza una búsqueda en el filtro de Datatables este solamente realiza la búsqueda sobre las filas padres de la tabla, en mi caso deseo que cuando realice la búsqueda también lo haga teniendo en cuenta los resultados de las filas hijas, si lo deseas puedes ver el siguiente [ejemplo](https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html) de la documentación, si intentas buscar una _extensión_ de cualquier fila hija esta no te va aparecer.

Comment: @AmilcarAngeles Así lo trate de explicar, ya si viste el ejemplo es lo que requiero, buscar teniendo en cuenta los valores que se encuentran en las filas hijas, espero haberte aclarado mejor la pregunta, cualquier duda adicional con gusto lo puedo explicar.

Comment: Ahí te he puesto una respuesta y un código de muestra para que lo pruebes.

Answer (score 1):

Para que jQuery DataTables busque filas secundarias, debe agregar los datos que se muestran en las filas secundarias a la tabla principal como columnas ocultas.

Por ejemplo, puede agregar una columna oculta para `extn` la propiedad de datos usando la opción `columns.visible` como se muestra a continuación:

**JavaScript:**

```
  "columns": [
        {
            "class":          'details-control',
            "orderable":      false,
            "data":           null,
            "defaultContent": ''
        },
        { "data": "name" },
        { "data": "position" },
        { "data": "office" },
        { "data": "salary" },
        { "data": "extn", "visible": false }            
    ],
```

**HTML :**

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Position</th>
        <th>Office</th>
        <th>Salary</th>
        <th>Extn.</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

**MANIFESTACIÓN**

Vea este [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h2u4fowj/) para obtener código y demostración. Busque 1562 y se mostrará la primera fila aunque los datos aparezcan solo en la fila secundaria.

Éxitos.

Comment: Esta respuesta parecer funcionar muy bien para este ejemplo, podrías agregar una nueva respuesta en base al código de la pregunta inicial para darle la validación correcta.

Comment: En tu tabla de datos tienes funciones ciclos foreach y variables que no se corren en el simulador por la falta de datos, en cambio para poder explicarte no he utilizado datos dinámicos, más bien estáticos, adpatarlo no sería de una vez pues tengo el tiempo complicado, pero básicamente es reemplazar.

Comment: Agradezco si me apoyas en adaptar el código de tu respuesta al de mi pregunta inicial, se me hace un poco difícil por la manera en que estoy recorriendo los datos.

Comment: En la respuesta te explico como hacerlo. Donde tienes tus columnas añades  { "data": "extn", "visible": false }  y con tus ciclos le añades los datos.

Comment: Tuviste oportunidad de adaptar tu respuesta a mi pregunta inicial ?

Comment: He vuelto a lanzar una recompensa a mi pregunta, en esta ocasión busco una respuesta mas detallada, lo que requiero ahora es adaptar tu respuesta en base a mi pregunta inicial, te animarías a conseguirlo ?

Comment: Esta respuesta no es correcta, el OP carga los datos dinámicamente, no carga todos los datos a la vez, las subtablas las carga desde una función en un botón en la tabla padre, así que esta manera que propones no le sirve, es mas, en una tabla con gran cantidad de datos, esta manera no es implementable ya que datatables funciona de *aquella manera* y tardaría mucho en obtener los datos y procesarlos